# Create hexagonal field with flat tiles with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, hexagonal-tiles

I want to create an hexagonal field with flat tiles in JavaFX. The following stackoverflow question allows to create a field with pointy tiles: [Create hexagonal field with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165602/create-hexagonal-field-with-javafx/68128676)

This code example works perfectly with pointy tiles:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UISolution extends Application {

    private final static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    private final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

    private final static double r= 20; // the inner radius from hexagon center to outer corner
    private final static double n= Math.sqrt(r * r * 0.75); // the inner radius from hexagon center to middle of the axis
    private final static double TILE_HEIGHT = 2 * r;
    private final static double TILE_WIDTH = 2 * n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane tileMap = new AnchorPane();
        Scene content = new Scene(tileMap, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(content);

        int rowCount = 4; // how many rows of tiles should be created
        int tilesPerRow = 6; // the amount of tiles that are contained in each row
        int xStartOffset = 40; // offsets the entire field to the right
        int yStartOffset = 40; // offsets the entire fiels downwards

        for (int x = 0; x < tilesPerRow; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
                double xCoord = x * TILE_WIDTH + (y % 2) * n + xStartOffset;
                double yCoord = y * TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75 + yStartOffset;
                
                Polygon tile = new Tile(xCoord, yCoord);
                tileMap.getChildren().add(tile);
            }
        }
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class Tile extends Polygon {
        Tile(double x, double y) {
            // creates the polygon using the corner coordinates
            getPoints().addAll(
                    x, y,
                    x, y + r,
                    x + n, y + r * 1.5,
                    x + TILE_WIDTH, y + r,
                    x + TILE_WIDTH, y,
                    x + n, y - r * 0.5
            );

            // set up the visuals and a click listener for the tile
            setFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
            setStrokeWidth(1);
            setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Clicked: " + this));
        }
    }
}
```

I think that I only have to modify the part here:

```
     getPoints().addAll(
         x, y,
         x, y + r,
         x + n, y + r * 1.5,
         x + TILE_WIDTH, y + r,
         x + TILE_WIDTH, y,
         x + n, y - r * 0.5
     );
```

but I'm struggling to have a correct shape and position for my tiles. And if I'm doing:

```
  getPoints().addAll(x, y,
     x + n * 0.5, y + r,
     x + n * 1.5, y + r,
     x + TILE_WIDTH, y,
     x + n * 1.5, y - r,
     x + n * 0.5, y - r
  );
```

the tiles have a correct flat shape but are not positioned correctly relative to each other. I think that this time I should modify the following code:

```
     double xCoord = x * TILE_WIDTH + (y % 2) * n + xStartOffset;
     double yCoord = y * TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75 + yStartOffset;
```

An example of the pointy tiles result with this code:

[image]

Comment: I fixed the example RADIUS_N was n and RADIUS_N was r

Comment: What's the difference between a "flat tile" and a "pointy tile"?  Can you provide images of the tiles and the field you are trying to create?  Are you actually trying to create a [regular octagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagon#Regular_octagon) rather than a hexagon?  Note, you can't create a tiled field comprised of only regular octagons.

Comment: This site explains a lot of things about flat or pointy hexagonal grid: [redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) Sadly I was still not able to use it to change the initial "pointy" JavaFX implementation to have a "flat" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for flat tiles. Here it is:

```
package org.hexagon.check;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class HexagonFlat extends Application {
   private final static double TILE_WIDTH = 20;
   private final static double TILE_HEIGHT = TILE_WIDTH;
   private final static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
   private final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
   double v = Math.sqrt(3) / 2.0;
   double v2 = Math.sqrt(3);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      AnchorPane tileMap = new AnchorPane();
      Scene content = new Scene(tileMap, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
      primaryStage.setScene(content);

      int rowCount = 4; // how many rows of tiles should be created
      int tilesPerRow = 6; // the amount of tiles that are contained in each row
      int xStartOffset = 40; // offsets the entire field to the right
      int yStartOffset = 40; // offsets the entire fiels downwards
      for (int y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
         double yCoordInit = yStartOffset + y * TILE_WIDTH * v2;
         double yCoord = yCoordInit;
         for (int x = 0; x < tilesPerRow; x++) {
            double xCoord = 1.5 * x * TILE_WIDTH + xStartOffset;
            Polygon tile = new Tile(xCoord, yCoord);
            tileMap.getChildren().add(tile);
            yCoord = yCoord == yCoordInit ? yCoord + TILE_HEIGHT * v : yCoordInit;
         }
      }
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   private class Tile extends Polygon {
      Tile(double x, double y) {
         // creates the polygon using the corner coordinates
         getPoints().addAll(
            x, y,
            x + TILE_WIDTH, y,
            x + TILE_WIDTH * 1.5, y + TILE_HEIGHT * v,
            x + TILE_WIDTH, y + TILE_HEIGHT * v2,
            x, y + TILE_WIDTH * v2,
            x - (TILE_WIDTH / 2.0), y + TILE_HEIGHT * v
         );
         // set up the visuals and a click listener for the tile
         setFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
         setStrokeWidth(1);
         setStroke(Color.BLACK);
         setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Clicked: " + this));
      }
   }
}
```

The result is:

[image]